# TYPO3: search with many custom content elements

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

Normally, ext:ke_search is a great solution for any TYPO3 website search.

It can also be extended quite quickly. Though, the current blueprint to extend it is quite old school, pibase style.

Now I have a site that mainly consists of custom content elements (mask).

Should I rather do all the ke_search extending, or risk another look at indexed_search/crawler, which (I think) is even more oldschool?

Or is there a third way apart from solr?

ps: maybe an idea: combine crawler and ke_search - will look at that

Answer (score 0):

Definitively ke_search.

When I posted the question, I didn't realize you can extend the CTypes it searches in the indexer config, and/or add an extended pages indexer quickly.